# Is there a un-minified JavaScript version of the FireBase API?

Tags: lua, firebase

I'm working on an interface for a device who provides an API through FireBase, but I'm not working in Java, JavaScript, or any other language FireBase provides libraries for.

I'm using Lua, and while I can easily implement the REST API, I'd like to be able to use the WebSocket API, as firebase.js provides.

I can create a WebSocket connection, but don't know how the authorization functionality works in firebase.js, and was wondering if there's an 'un-minified' version of firebase.js, so I can see how the authentication call works.

Comment: There's a minified version available at http://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-debug.js but please keep in mind that the wire protocol over websockets may change at any time!

Comment: going further, is there one with comments etc. around?

Comment: Understood, but as I'm writing a client that doesn't have anything other than Lua as a language, I don't have many options.  I can use the REST API for commands, and could even poll with the REST API, but that's not terribly efficient for a driver that's meant to be updated all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol that Firebase uses to communicate with its client libraries is not a documented API. You might be able to reverse engineer it, but since it's not a documented API, it could change at any time.

You may want to investigate Firebase's [REST Streaming](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-streaming), which allows you to listen for changes to a location. Here's an example of what the server could send, per the docs:

```
// Set your entire cache to {"a": 1, "b": 2}
event: put
data: {"path": "/", "data": {"a": 1, "b": 2}}
// Put the new data in your cache under the key 'c', so that the complete cache now looks like:
// {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": {"foo": true, "bar": false}}
event: put
data: {"path": "/c", "data": {"foo": true, "bar": false}}
```

Also, the Firebase client that @Anant mentions in his comment is a [deprecated version](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html) that's very old.

Comment: Thanks.  Since posting this question, Nest / FireBase have released REST Streaming, which much better fits what I was trying to do.  I no longer use WebSockets, and don't have to reverse-engineer how to do the client API anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll add that recommendation to my answer.

Comment: This still royally sucks if you're trying to use Firebase on a server, such as a Ruby based server. Keep in mind the REST api has no transactions such as increments or aggregate updates etc. This severely limits what you can use Firebase for.

Comment: @Corey Agreed. The REST API should only be used as a last resort. If you're using a server worker node, try to use the Java or JavaScript (node.js) clients instead. They'll give you all the fun realtime features and transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Un-minified/un-obfuscated debug versions of 2.x versions of the Firebase lib are available by appending `-debug` to the filename on the CDN. Eg [v2.4.2 debug version is here](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase-debug.js)

This no longer seems to be possible with v3+; [I've asked another question about that specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405000/is-there-an-un-obfuscated-un-minified-debug-version-of-the-firebase-v3-js-libr)

Update: the answer seems to be that no v3 debug version is available currently (2016-07-18)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13023226)

Comment: @jankigadhiya pretty sure I _have_ included the essential parts of the answer here -- the link was simply an example of what the URL should look like. I've added the answer from the other SO question