# Is there an un-obfuscated/un-minified (debug) version of the Firebase v3 JS libraries available?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Prior to version 3.0, a "debug" version of the library was available by appending `-debug` to the filename.

For example, v2.4.2 has [an obfuscated version](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js) and [a debug version](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase-debug.js), but v3.1.0 only seems to have [the obfuscated version](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js); [appending `-debug` to the filename gives a 404](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-debug.js)

Note: [an earlier question about pre-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601177/is-there-a-un-minified-javascript-version-of-the-firebase-api) is answered; this question is specifically about v3+

Comment: Anyone with the down votes or close votes willing to explain? I don't think Gabriel is asking for a recommendation and it looks like he's "done his homework".

Comment: the answer is "no" by the way. I'm checking to see if this has already been answered here, otherwise I'll write up an answer below.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen People are seeing a "request for a library", and robo-closing without realizing this is a legit question about a tool for programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/PuubUKUg_4Y/g5uKSn0CBQAJ) group:

> We unfortunately do not ship a debug version of the 3.x.x client. The reasons for this are a bit hard to get into, but it deals with how we build the SDK itself. We are hoping to bring back the debug version of the SDK in a future release, although I don't have a time estimate on that. Sorry I don't have better use. I'd love to hear your use cases (other than just using it to debug) if you have them